# Sorting and grouping array, hash with all items appears at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, grouping

I have a table with leaflets data which is sorted by date in controller:

```
@leaflets = Leaflet.order(:date)
```

And then grouped by dates in view (I found the code somewhere on the internet)

```
<%= @leaflets.group_by(&:date).each do |date, leaflets| %>
  <p><%= l(date, :format => '%A, %d %b %Y') %></p> <!-- localized date formatting: weekday, day month year -->


  <table>
    <tr>
      <% leaflets.each do |leaflet| %>

        <td style="border:dotted 1px; padding:5px;">

      <strong><%= leaflet.place %></strong><br/>
      <%= leaflet.description %><br/>
      <%= link_to "Zapisz się", leaflet_path(leaflet) %>
      </td>
      </a>
    <% end %>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <% end %>
```

Everything works great, but it prints all items as a hash at the end:

```
{Tue, 11 Nov 2014=>[#<Leaflet id: 14, date: "2014-11-11", place: "Miejsce11-11-A", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:58:01", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:58:01">, #<Leaflet id: 15, date: "2014-11-11", place: "Miejsce11-11-B", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:58:04", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:58:04">, #<Leaflet id: 16, date: "2014-11-11", place: "Miejsce11-11-C", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:58:07", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:58:07">], Mon, 01 Dec 2014=>[#<Leaflet id: 4, date: "2014-12-01", place: "Miejsce1", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:56:42", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:56:42">, #<Leaflet id: 5, date: "2014-12-01", place: "Miejsce2", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:56:55", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:56:55">, #<Leaflet id: 6, date: "2014-12-01", place: "Miejsce3", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:01", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:01">], Tue, 02 Dec 2014=>[#<Leaflet id: 7, date: "2014-12-02", place: "Miejsce02-A", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:21", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:21">, #<Leaflet id: 8, date: "2014-12-02", place: "Miejsce02-B", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:24", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:24">, #<Leaflet id: 9, date: "2014-12-02", place: "Miejsce02-C", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:28", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:28">], Fri, 05 Dec 2014=>[#<Leaflet id: 10, date: "2014-12-05", place: "Miejsce05-A", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:40", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:40">, #<Leaflet id: 11, date: "2014-12-05", place: "Miejsce05-B", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:43", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:43">, #<Leaflet id: 12, date: "2014-12-05", place: "Miejsce05-C", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:46", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:46">, #<Leaflet id: 13, date: "2014-12-05", place: "Miejsce05-D", description: nil, program: nil, modifier: nil, created_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:48", updated_at: "2014-12-05 21:57:48">]}
```

Any idea what's wrong? Is it normal behaviour for grouping in Rails? How can I delete this big hash?
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA4kt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `=` from:

```
<%= @leaflets.group_by(&:date).each do |date, leaflets| %>
```

So that it reads:

```
<% @leaflets.group_by(&:date).each do |date, leaflets| %>
```

The `=` is outputing the results of the `each` call.

Comment: Thank you! I would propably come up with this after 2 weeks of thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

The `each` method returns the object you called `each` on. In ERB, `<%= ... %>` will *display the result* of the evaluated code, which is `@leaflets.group_by(&:date)` in this case. Simply remove the `=` sign to silently evaluate the code:

```
<% @leaflets.group_by(&:date).each do |date, leaflets| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I would propably come up with this after 2 weeks of thinking :)